# How to Using Platform Styles in android

Tags: android, xml, styles

i have this xml code :

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

in `style` attribute the value is "@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
 and there is no styles in my `styles.xml` , so i read this is a **"Platform Styles"** so why  is not start with `android:` like this "@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar" ??

Comment: Because it comes with the support-appcompat library...which is a "third-party, first-party" lib...

Comment: so how can i find this library?

Comment: It is inside the sdk directory, mine is `D:\Android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0`. Do `CTRL`+`Left mouse button` to view the style implementation

Comment: This is a style defined in the AppCompat library, which is a dependency for your project. The styles defined there are compiled into your project, hence they are in your app's local namespace, not in the `android` namespace.

Comment: what do you mean by "third-party, first-party"??

Comment: Means, support libs are not included in core platform, but developed by the same guys from google android team.